# Android: Device Administration Application

Tags: android, uninstallation, device-admin

How do I prevent my device administration application from being installed?  I have created the application and enabled it in location and security, but I can still uninstall it or disable it without asking for a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that's impossible (fortunately), unless you have complete control of the device and install your own package manager?

Comment: You just need to change that code here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#PackageManagerService